# Purpose of taking volatile variable in ThreadLocal instance

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

This is one of questions asked to me in one of the technical talks.

```
public class MyClass {

    volatile int i;
}
```

I am using the above MyClass as a ThreadLocal, so what is the use of taking any volatile variable inside this?

```
final ThreadLocal<MyClass> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<MyClass>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that instance is used exclusively with `ThreadLocal` and not passed around, there doesn't appear to be much point in `volatile`.

Note, however, that `MyClass` is just a class like any other: there's nothing preventing it from being used in contexts not involving thread-local storage. In those contexts it could well make sense for the variable to be `volatile`.

Comment: Did you mean that If I am using MyClass only in threadlocal context, then there is no use of volatile. However, if it is used outside this context then yes, it could well make sense for the variable to be volatile.

Answer (score 0):

Volatile keyword in Java guarantees that value of volatile variable will always be read from main memory and not from Thread's local cache.

Volatile variable can be used as an alternative way of achieving synchronization in Java in some cases, like Visibility. with volatile variable its guaranteed that all reader thread will see updated value of volatile variable once write operation  completed, without volatile keyword different reader thread may see different values. Let's understand this with help of an example.

```
public class C {
   private volatile int COUNTER=0;

    public static void main(String... q)
    {
        new C().call();
    }

    public void call()
    {
        new A().start();
        new B().start();
    }

    class A extends Thread
    {
        public void run()
        {
            int i =0;
            while(i<100)
            {
                COUNTER++;
                System.out.println(" A COUNTER : "+COUNTER+" *** "+"i : "+i);
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    class B extends Thread
    {
        public void run()
        {
            int i =0;
            while(i<100)
            {
                COUNTER++;
                 System.out.println(" B COUNTER : "+COUNTER+" *** "+"i : "+i);
                   try{
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
                i++;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I have shared COUNTER variable between two threads and have used volatile instead of putting synchronization so that value updated will be shared globally in main memory and other thread will get updated value.

Just try above code again by replacing :

private volatile int COUNTER=0;

with

private  int COUNTER=0;

re-run the program and note the difference.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

> public class ThreadLocal
>
> This class provides thread-local variables. These variables differ
>   from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one
>   (via its get or set method) has its own, independently initialized
>   copy of the variable.

According to [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)

> The Java programming language allows threads to access shared
>   variables (§17.1). As a rule, to ensure that shared variables are
>   consistently and reliably updated, a thread should ensure that it has
>   exclusive use of such variables by obtaining a lock that,
>   conventionally, enforces mutual exclusion for those shared variables.
>
> The Java programming language provides a second mechanism, volatile
>   fields, that is more convenient than locking for some purposes.

So, in your example each thread has its own instance of MyClass. If it is the only using of MyClass, concurrent access to `i` is to allowed.

volatile is key word for "more convenient than locking" mechanism for "enforces mutual exclusion".

So, you do not need volatile in this code.

In addition, it decreases performance.